# How to set language on highcharts.client.Chart

Tags: gwt, highcharts

HOW does one set the language on org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts.client.Chart
setting the Highcharts.options (in Java) as:

```
Highcharts.Options options = new Highcharts.Options();
options.setGlobal(new Global().setUseUTC(false));
String[] cat = new String[] {"Jan.", "Fev.", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Set.", "Out.", "Nov.", "Dez."} ;
options.setLang(new Lang().setMonths(cat));
Highcharts.setOptions(options);
```

has NO effect. Remains in English.

trying to set:

```
chart.getXAxis()
.setCategories("Jan.", "Fev.", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Set.", "Out.", "Nov.", "Dez.");
```

fails:
--> Chromium fails:
V8 error: Allocation failed - process out of memory (invalid array length). Current memory usage: 890 MB

--> Firefox complains of a script error

Fails even using documented example of:

```
chart.getXAxis().setCategories(....)
```

HELP please!

Answer (score 2):

Lol!
I needed to

```
options.setLang(new Lang().setShortMonths(cat));
```

!!!